# Customize Radscheduler

Tags: silverlight, radscheduler

I want to customize radscheduleView calendar navigation control. The resultant Control have the same calendar control of the standard radscheduleView with an additional Combo box which contains years.On selecting the year,the scheduleview control should Navigate to the Year selected with already selected timespan. How can I achieve this functionality?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should move this to radschedulerview tag and not radscheduler.